# React native -Firestore - Retreive auth user email id based on user table filed value

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Am developing one firestore application in react native and i have db with table users. Inside user table, each element structure will be like this[image: Firestore user db structure]

Now my requirement is to get the auth users email id using the uid from users table if users-> Info-> Subscription->active subscription value is true. User email id is present in the authentication tab and I would like to connect the uid from users table to that authentication users list. Could you please help me how can I do that query?

Comment: The screenshot you have shared is from Firebase Realtime Database and not Firestore. Do you know UID of the user while querying ?

Comment: Am doing it for the first time and I can see the uid under users table starts with nl84kssj... (from screenshot). This user id is in the authentication tab when I do a search. But I don't know how can we implemet here in react native.

Comment: What I meant is - you are trying to get subscription status of currently logged in user right ?

Comment: No. Based on the active subscription value I need to get user email id. For example, If user 1 has activesubscription value true then I need user1 email id which is visible in the  authentication tab.

Comment: Can you share an export of your database? You can download it as JSON by clicking vertical ellipses on top right corner.

Comment: Sure. But how can I attach that json file here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237728/discussion-between-pratheeja-and-dharmaraj).